# MP3 audio deep explore

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, mp3

I am looking for recommendations for software that will tell me the contents of an mp3 file. The problem I have is that I made a recording in which I had mutiple goes at a speech. I used Audacity to chop out the bits I didnt need and tidy it up. It plays just like I want. I have inserted it into PowerPoint and it works and sounds fine. However, when I generete  Full HD movie it seem that the audio has some of my previous takes in it !

So I am wondering if theres some hidden tracks or something in there?

Comment: As far as I am aware, it isn't possible to "hide" audio in MP3 files.

Comment: Is it possible you've embedded an older version of the file in PowerPoint? In PowerPoint you can embed the audio or you can simply "link" to the file...

Comment: I ended up using a .wav, instead of .mp3, and it worked fine. The other thing I did was link to the file instead of embedding it - perhaps that fixed it.